# issue with jquery external linking

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I am working on jquery. I have 4 tabs within the `<li>` tags. I have used jquery 1.9.1.js for my project. my `<li>` looks like the one below. I got a solution to use http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#api-reference. But the fact is that I have used and imported this external lib but it doesn't seem to work. The thing which i am trying to attain is when ever I select the specific `<li>` item and press f5 the page by default loads the first `<li>` item. But the thing which I am looking for is , it has to load the same selected `<li>` item and its contents when refreshed. any help would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="coolbar">
        <div class="cool-inner">
            <ul id="mybar" class="nav cool-tabs">
                <li class="Coke">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Coke </a><span class="dashboard-bottom"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="Fanta">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Fanta</a><span class="Pricing-bottom"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="Pepsi">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Pepsi</a><span class="Promotion-bottom"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="Limca">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Limca</a><span class="Product-bottom"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>.
<div id="login"> 
    <button type="button" id="submit" value="Login" class="btn">Click me for cool drinks</button>
</div>
```

And my jquery code for page refresh:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() { 
        $('.container').show();
        $('#login').hide();
        $.cookie('shown', true);
    });
    if ($.cookie('shown')) {
        $('#submit').click()
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when activating the tab you may want to set the tabs position/value in the cookie and when the page loads, check if tabs position/value exist in the cookie, then accordingly activate that tab or trigger click event on that tab.

may this help

Comment: but i am even using a pieec of jquery code to make the page reload with the same content